# Kentia Palm brown leaves

Tags: houseplants, palm, kentia

I’ve read a few previous Kentia Palm questions but unfortunately, I’m still confused as to what is happening with my plant.

I bought it about 3 months ago from Harris Farm (if that’s any use). I haven’t re-potted it but I’ve been watering it, with worm tea from our work farm, when the top inch of soil is dry, which has worked out about weekly-ish. I also mist it about weekly-ish too.

Instead of using fertiliser, I’ve put a bit of soil from the worm farm around the base - I’ve done this twice as long as I’ve had it.

It’s in the living room and gets a fair amount of indirect light.

I’m pretty sure I’m doing everything by the book, but yet some of the baby leaves at the bottom have completely dried up and turned brown, and now some of the bigger leaves are turning brown.

Please help my dear plant

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Turning brown from the tips?

Comment: Pictures please!

Comment: I’ve added pictures now. It’s the whole leaf that is turning brown, although I guess the tips are too.

Answer (score 1):

While most Palms typically Love sunlight Kentia's like indirect sun. Give your plants some space away from the window and dampen the soil again. Also this browning is seen of various of dryness. Mist your palm with either rainwater or distilled water 3 times a week. Humidity keeps them healthy